# Insert Excel Formula via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

as a continuation from another question, I'm trying to solve my problems inserting a formula via VBA on a macro.

Here's my code:

```
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(C1=""LPPD"";""MIPRU"";IF(C1=""LPGR"";""DCT"";IF(OR(C1=""LPFL"";C1=""LPCR"");""LADOX"";IF(OR(C1=""LPPI"";C1=""LPSJ"";C1=""LPHR"");""NOTMA"";""ERRO""))))"
```

For some reason, and the code doesn't show any errors, when I try to run it I get:

> Run-time error ("Application-defined or object-defined error")

Worth mentioning I'm using Excel 2003.

Hope I'll be able to find my answer with you guys! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA is US-EN centric, so using the `.Formula` the formulas must be with `,` instead of `;`:

```
Range("F1").Formula = "=IF(C1=""LPPD"",""MIPRU"",IF(C1=""LPGR"",""DCT"",IF(OR(C1=""LPFL"",C1=""LPCR""),""LADOX"",IF(OR(C1=""LPPI"",C1=""LPSJ"",C1=""LPHR""),""NOTMA"",""ERRO""))))"
```

Or you can use `.FormulaLocal`

```
Range("F1").FormulaLocal = "=IF(C1=""LPPD"";""MIPRU"";IF(C1=""LPGR"";""DCT"";IF(OR(C1=""LPFL"";C1=""LPCR"");""LADOX"";IF(OR(C1=""LPPI"";C1=""LPSJ"";C1=""LPHR"");""NOTMA"";""ERRO""))))"
```

Comment: I'm just using semicolons due to the fact that this is Excel 2003. At least for regular Excel formulas I can't use the comma and I have to use semi-colons. Is it different for VBA?

Comment: Yes,  as I stated, vba is US-EN centric.  In the US we use `,` in our formulas not `;`.  The use of `;` over `,` is not based on excel version but on local settings.  Hence the need to use `.FormulaLocal` when using `;` in vba.  It tells vba to look at you local settings and use those when parsing the formula.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I never got that the commas were a local issue. Always thought that it was a matter of the Excel Version! Thanks a lot!